# Querying for multiple values when an error message is present in AWS Timestream

Tags: aws, amazontimestream

I am using AWS Timestream so the DB structure is a bit different than normal but effectively it fairly similar to a normal structure.
What I need to do:
When an error message of a certain type (Ie measure_name = "DriveError") I would like to query that error message and the last value of of several other measures all of which will have a different measure_name. The point of this is to help quickly view my systems state when that error occurred. I am using this to watch a machines in a factory so the values are not server related but one could basically view an example as :
*An error occurs,
report in a table:
the error,
the the cpu temp,
the cpu utilization,
the fan speed,
ect.
*

The following would be the normal way I could select a error message

```
SELECT time, measure_value::varchar AS error
from "Main"."Machine1"
where measure_name = 'DriveError'
ORDER BY 
    time DESC
```

But in this case what I will need to is select the last value of all my drive parameters (again each has its own measure_name) when there is measure_value::varchar with measure_name = DriveError.

Comment: i am guessing you use postgres sop please tag it cprrectly, aws is a a serviuce not a rdms

Comment: I use aws Timestream as stated in the title

Comment: ok i added a tag for thatit looks like postgres and has window functions [last_value(x)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/window-functions.html) userhat for measure_value and order by time desc